Message ID from Google Apps Script is different from ID from Gmail API
I am trying to build a Google Workspace Add-on card that pulls some information from a sheet and adds it to a Gmail card.
On the sheet, I have a list of emails with their Message ID pulled from the API (example: 1930e10b19e703er)
But the Message ID I am trying to match it to from Google Apps Script Add on function onGmailMessageOpen is different (example: "msg-f:1815195880117154226")
So it's unable to match ids and therefore can't pull in any info from the Sheet/CSV. I would like the Apps Script ID to be the same as the ID from the API.
I have tried various different methods. Here is the part of the latest script pulling in the ID.

function onGmailMessageOpen(eventObject) {
  // Defensive check for the event object
  if (!eventObject || !eventObject.gmail) {
    return createDefaultCard('No email context available');
  }

  // Activate temporary Gmail scopes to allow message metadata to be read.
  var accessToken = eventObject.gmail.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

  // Get the ID of the message the user has open
  var messageId = eventObject.gmail.messageId;
  
  // Log the extracted message ID
  Logger.log('Retrieved Message ID: "' + messageId + '"');

  // Find implications from spreadsheet based on the messageId
  var implications = findImplications(messageId);

  // Create and return card
  return createImplicationsCard(implications);
}


In the logs it says Searching for EXACT Message ID: "msg-f:1815195880117154226"
And then "ID in sheet: "1930e10b19e703er""
I have also tried  "var messageId = e.gmail.messageId;" which also returns these same 'msg-f" ids.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Could you please share what createDefaultCard means in your code

"On the sheet, I have a list of emails with their Message ID pulled from the API" please be more specific . Do you used the Class GmailApp, Advanced GMail Service or other way to the messages id?

From Reddit, OP says "I was able to finally fix this." Would you please post an answer to your own question in the forum.
